# Can one eat avodah zarah food?

Tags: food, avodah-zarah

My question is simple: Can food offered as avodah zarah be eaten? Why?

Comment: @Yehonathan I am assuming (based on the question mark at the end of the sentence) that a question was intended, and have edited the wording to make that more obvious. If that's not your intention, you should be able to roll back the edit.

Comment: It is forbidden, see https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah111/

Comment: Do you mean like the food in a restaurant that was placed before an idol before being served to the patrons? I remember a story in which the waiters did this and the restaurant was closed down until the staff was replaced and the mashgiach was able to ensure that it would not happen again.

Answer (score 3):

Food offered to Avodah Zarah falls under the category of Tikrovet Avodah Zarah, offerings to an idol, and are prohibited from benefit absolutely. See [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 139](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.139?lang=bi) for details.

Comment: Maybe you could quote the relevant passage(s)?

Comment: Is it possible now to ask the rationale? What happens to the food in a spiritual sense that makes it forbidden? Does it kind of "absorbs" impurity and therefore is forbidden?